# ExperienceBundle deployment error - "Your site needs a route with route type too-many-requests. Update your file and try again."

Tags: community, deployment, community-builder, deployment-error

I tried to deploy ExperienceBundle my sandbox to our integration sandbox, but I kept getting the following error:

> Your site needs a route with route type too-many-requests. Update your file and try again.

In Experience builder, I was able to access the page "Too Many Requests", but when I tried to retrieve the whole Experience Bundle using workbench and package.xml, the page was not there. Yet, I wasn't able to deploy the bundle without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to edit markup of the default HTML Editor component. I didn't want too many changes, so I just changed the content a little. After that, I was able to retrieve the bundle with this page (included both in views and routes folders). Then, I simply added it to the ExperienceBundle I wanted to deploy.

[image: "Too Many Requests" page in the Experience Builder]